# Assign equal or less with zero target number against another array in php

Tags: php, arrays, random, assign

Candidate `array= {10, 1, 2, 7, 6, 1, 5};`

Target `Number = 15`

Can distribute random target `number=15` into candidate array?

Possible output of could be:

Assign equal or less with zero target number against candidate array like is:

```
 $output =array([10] => [2],[1]=>[0], [2]=>[2], [7]=>[5], [6]=>[3],  [1]=>[1], [5]=>[2]);
```

Comment: you can calculate sum of array and distribute `number` according to the values of array like `array[i]+=(array[i]/sum)*number`

Comment: Hi Man, I did try but output is not correct. <?php $candidate_array=array(10, 1, 2, 7, 6, 1, 5);
$sum=array_sum($candidate_array); //sum=32
$number=15;

$compare=array();
$i=0;
foreach($candidate_array as $values){
 $candidate_array[$i]+=($candidate_array[$i]/$sum)*$number;
 $i++;
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($candidate_array); ?>

Comment: what made this decision ? [10] => [2] ?

Comment: @tan left [10] arrays are candidate array and right [2] arrays are random number of targetnumbers. Actually i want to assign random out of total number=15 of arrays value to candidate arrays

Comment: Will it be okey if [10] => [9] ?

Comment: @tan Simply i want to total number=15 divide equal or less value to candidate array values.

Comment: @tan Yes you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, This will extract a random no between 1 & cardiate_array[$i]. After that it will reduce the target distribution number by that random number. Will continue until targetNumber is fully consumed.

```
$candidate_array = array(10, 1, 2, 7, 6, 0, 5);
$i = 0;

$newArray = [] ;
$number = 15; 

//Precaution
$sum = array_sum($candidate_array) ;
if( $number > $sum ) {
    //we can only distribute only $sum amount maximum.
    $number = $sum ; 
}

//repeat until fully consumed.
while( $number > 0 ) {
    foreach( $candidate_array as $i => $val ) {
        if( ! isset($newArray[$i]) ) {
            $newArray[$i] = 0 ;
        }
        if( $number > 0 ) {
            if( $val > 0 ) {
                if( $newArray[$i] < $candidate_array[$i] ) {
                    //Find the maximum can be applied 
                    $max = $candidate_array[$i] - $newArray[$i] ;
                    //Second iteration ? limit max value. This can be improved more.
                    if( $max > $number ) {
                        $max = $number ;
                    }
                    $rnd = rand(1,$max ) ;
                    //EDIT: A rand results in integer value, which again check with max (float) value. There is possibility of extra 0.5 added in result array which will be solved here.
                    if( $rnd > $max ) {
                        $rnd = $max ;
                    }
                    $newArray[$i] += $rnd ;
                    //Consume the number assigned.
                    $number -= $rnd ;
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I checked working fine with above arrays but when i'm changing the array like $candidate_array = array(10, 1, 2.5, 7.5, 6, 0, 5);  and $number = 32; then output not showing correct...

Comment: thanks for helping and I need some more help for decimal value

Comment: I did used rand() function avoid fractional values. will update the answer.

Comment: When i'm placing this line in below $rnd=rand(1,$max); than random not working $rnd =((float)($max)==(int)($rnd))? $rnd:$max; Can i place decimal value=decimal value? and other values can be random with int value?

Comment: I've already updated the answer to become compatible with float. please check //EDIT:

Comment: Oh Sorry, Thanks again. Actually i want distribute decimal value  only against decimal value. Can be possible? If passing number=30;

Comment: $candidate_array = array(10, 1, 2.5, 7.5, 6, 0, 5); and $number = 30; It is assigning number against like Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2.5
    [3] => 6  //7.5
    [4] => 6
    [5] => 0
    [6] => 1.5 ). Can possible that 1.5 or other decimal value place only candidate array decimal value?

Comment: Second thing is I want to write update query in foreach loop or will be write another foreach loop? When i'm writing update query in foreach loop in this condition : if( $newArray[$i] < $candidate_array[$i] ) { //update query

Comment: array(10, 1, 2.5, 7.5, 6, 0, 5); and $number = 30; in this case if we give 1.5 against 7.5 it will you have to compromise some other value also. since it has 0.5 left.